# Open an Existing File in Catia V5 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, catia

I have tried so much but I can't find an answer.
How do I open an existing File using Python? When I try running my script, Catia always says:

> Document cannot be read

I've tried this:

```
CATIA.Documents.Open("z:\tmp\kge\444YYY\iso4017.CATPart")
```

also I have tried creating a Product and adding a existing part with: `AddComponentsFromFiles`

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert in Python, but I guess backslashes in string literals need some special handling like in most other languages. Try double backslashes. https://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Thank you very much @gdir!!! It worked perfectly!!!